# Joining two datatables as parent-child in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to build a typed list of parent-child objects that are read from two different Excel sources: One describes parent object, another describes child objects. The hierarchy is only 2 layers ever.
Reading into excel is not the issue, as it is read into 2 untyped datatables, but joining the information is.

The structure is very plain:
Parent has an ID and some text fields
Children have a parentID (so its 1-m) and some text fields

The objects that these are to be populated into looks like this:

```
public class ParkingSites
{
    public List<ParkingLot> Lots { get; set; }

    public ParkingSites(List<ParkingLot> arg)
    {
        Lots = arg;
    }
}

public class ParkingLot
{
    public List<Bay> Bays{ get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> ParkingLotDetails { get; set; } 
    public ParkingLot()
    {

    }
}

public class Bay
{
    public List<string> BayDetails { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }    
    public Bay()
    {

    }
}
```

The excel sources have a fixed column order with the parent sheet's first column being the parentId, and the first column on the child sheet also being the parentId.

EDIT: After playing around a bit, I just made both parent and child classes typed, as the initial reason for leaving them mostly untyped lead to more problems than it prevented. This is part of a larger project where the untypedness is a better solution for our problem on the other classes with data that is not hierarchial.

Comment: So `Bay` should have some kind of `ParkingLotId`, and `ParkingLot` should have an `Id` and a `ParkingSiteId` etc.?

Comment: See my updated question. ParkingSites is really just a list of ParkingLots, and no more.

Comment: So how do you know which string in `Bay.BayDetails` refers to which string in `ParkingLost.ParkingLotDetails`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply group the list of children by the parent id, and then iterate over the parents and add each child that belongs to it.

For example, you could use `ToLookup`:

```
// assuming you have all Bay instances in a collection called bays
var baymap = bays.ToLookup(b => b.ParentId);

// and all ParkingLot instances in a collection called lots
foreach(var lot in lots)
    lot.Bays.AddRange(baymap[lot.Id]);
```

or, using the first element in the details lists:

```
var baymap = bays.ToLookup(b => b.BayDetails[0]);

foreach(var lot in lots)
    lot.Bays.AddRange(baymap[lot.ParkingLotDetails[0]]);
```

or, using `Where` without a lookup (probably slower, depends on your data):

```
foreach(var lot in lots)
    lot.Bays.AddRange(bays.Where(b => b.ParentId == lot.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked for me, and I ended up creating a fully typed class for parent and child each as it was too messy to continue with the untyped data. This is part of a much larger Integration testing project, and so far I have been able to use untyped for passing test values into tests, with QA team members only having to wait a few minutes for a new test field to be added. This is the first hierarchial test data read from a spreadsheet, and the pattern for the others turned out not to be correct. Oh, well YLAL!